# Api WhatsApp web js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, whatsapp

Estoy utilizando la documentación por defecto de la api de "WhatsApp web js" y al momento de aplicar el código

```
   console.log("no ahi conecxion ")
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
    sessionData = session;
    fs.writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
});

client.initialize();
```

al momento de que se escanea el qr, me sale el siguiente error

```
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
at Object.writeFile (node:fs:2106:5)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Brian\OneDrive\Escritorio\Bot\app.js:24:12)
at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Client.initialize (C:\Users\Brian\OneDrive\Escritorio\Bot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:223:14)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
```

code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'

Comment: Interesante... Y ya investigaste qué significa el error? Cómo has intentado corregirlo? Cómo te podemos ayudar? Sabes si `session` es de tipo `string` o una instanccia de `Buffer`, `TypedArray`, o`DataView`? Tienes un link a la documentación de whatsapp?

Comment: Esta es la documentación que estoy ocupando: https://wwebjs.dev/guide/authentication.html#noauth-strategy, por lo que entendí, no esta recibiendo la session, estuve revisando si ahi alguna pregunta con el mismo problema y por lo que vi, puede ser algún error de las versiones

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Estas intentando utilizar el inicio de sesion Legacy de la libreria whatsapp-web.js de pedroslopez.
Esta forma de inicio de sesion se encuentra deprecada.
Actualmente se utiliza MD (multi-device).
para más info https://wwebjs.dev/guide/authentication.html

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).